# Fragment: DIRECT access to common data over parent activity -> any disadvantages?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using a SlidingPaneLayout with two fragments...

On the left side I show some general infos and on the right all the other infos...

If I use the default way, giving the data to the fragments over an intent, I have to keep the data synchronised between the two fragments.

So what are the disadvantages of sharing the data through the parent activity? Is there on? Or is their a reason why this should not be done?

Why not use following in the fragments:

```
Data d = ((ParentActivity) getActivity()).getSharedData()
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
Data d = (Data)intent.getExtras().getSerialisable("sharedData");
```

Comment: Also look at [`setTargetFragment()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment%28android.app.Fragment,%20int%29) and [`getTargetFragment()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment%28%29), in case you want fragments to directly contact each other.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than casting the Activity to a known custom Activity, let the Activity implement an interface, and cast it to that when the Fragment is attached to the Activity.

This way the Fragment isn't bound to Activity and can be reused in another Activity as long as it provides the interface.

This is the Google recommended way:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks